# What does this if statement return empty do in Bootstrap modal source code?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am checking the bootstrap modal source code, and found a line like this. What does this `if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return` do? It seems to me that whether the code inside the if() is evaluated to `false` or `true`, the rest of the code in this snippet will still be executed. so what is the point to set such line and `return` empty?

```
   Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()

    e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    this.escape()
    this.resize()

    $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal')

    this.$element
      .removeClass('in')
      .attr('aria-hidden', true)
      .off('click.dismiss.bs.modal')
      .off('mouseup.dismiss.bs.modal')

    this.$dialog.off('mousedown.dismiss.bs.modal')

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      this.$element
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      this.hideModal()
  }
```

Comment: If code inside `if` statement will be evaluated as `true`, `return` will prevent rest of code from executing

Comment: "It seems to me that whatever the code inside the if() is, the rest of the code in this snippet will still be executed" - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
```

This is more of one-liner for this

```
if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()){
    return;
}
```

This simply means that if the Modal is already shown (`this.isShown` will be true) OR if the event's default action is prevented, simply return from this method `without executing any further statements` - in this case, it means don't hide the modal.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` instruction is immediate and interrupts the execution of the function. As a result, any following instruction won't be executed.